# Displaying changing integer

Tags: android, string, edit

what I'm trying to do is basically to create an Android application that when you press a button, an variable will increase by 1. This variable is also going to be displayed and the increment have to be in "real time".

I understand that I have to create a button that calls a method that will increase a variable by one. I know how to do this already. However, when I want to display the variable I'm not sure how to proceed. Do I have to convert the variable to a text string (and import it to strings.xml) and then display it via the .xml file for the current activity?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must keep the variable somewhere (I suggest your Activity's class) but you don't have to import it to `strings.xml`. Let's just call it `myCounter` for now.

Does your activity has a  corresponding layout file with a `TextView`? If so, what is the `TextView` id? For example, in the `TextView` below, the id is `myText`:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello" />
```

What you need to do is update your `TextView`'s `text` value like this:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(myCounter));
```

This will be done inside your `Button`'s associated `onClick()` method.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `Button`
2. Create an instance variable, that you'll increment afterwards
3. Set an `onClickListener` to your `Button`
4. Increment the variable in your `onClickListener`
5. And finally set the new variable to your `TextView` via `TextView#setText(String.valueOf(var))`